# Was the episode "The Co-Pilot" in Season 2 supposed to be the pilot?

Tags: production, the-shield

In "The Shield" there is an episode in Season 2 that does not fit into the timeline of the other episodes: Episode 2x09 "The Co-Pilot".

It plays during the time of the opening of the Barn, so even before the first season and introduces the main characters.

There is no explanation why this *flashback* is occurring and it does not really seem to fit in there. There is nothing revealed that advances the plot of Season 2 somehow.

The name of the episode, the way it looks older than the other ones in the season and the somewhat forced discontinuity made me think that this might have been a pilot that maybe was disapproved.

- What is the story behind this episode?
- Was it filmed prior to season 1? Was it supposed to be the original pilot? If so, why did it not get aired?
- If it was indeed a cancelled pilot, why did it get aired in season 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not the Original Pilot. It didn't film prior to season 1. It's a flashback episode whose story takes place before S1E1.

> The title is a wordplay on the term "pilot" used to refer to the first
>   episode in a television series. Since this whole episode is a
>   flashback to events preceding the series pilot, it was coined as
>   "Co-Pilot".[(source)](http://theshield.wikia.com/wiki/Co-Pilot)
>
> One of the reasons for this flashback show in the middle of the season
>   was to allow the make-up team time to figure out to depict Ronnie's
>   facial disfigurement, following an act of violence that had occurred
>   to him in episode 2x7 "Barnstormers". [(source)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0699500/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)